# enlarging pane in tmux (C-b z) kills a pytest run

Tags: tmux

Is there a reason for my local pytest run to die right after I *Ctrl-b z*? Is there a signal that is sent and not catched by the tmux server and thus, somehow killing my pytest? (I think running the pytest in a non-tmux terminal, *Ctrl-b z* won't do a thing though I couldn't confirm that yet)

The same happens when trying to resize a pane (i.e. *Ctrl-b Press-Down-Arrow*)

Answer (score 1):

When tmux resizes it will ask the kernel to send SIGWINCH to the processes in the pane, it sounds like your application is not handling it correctly and is crashing or exiting.

Comment: I'm testing it right now. Is there a way to envelop my pytest run (i.e. my application) in a 'ignore sigwinch' closure?